# Получение "Истинного имени" процесса

Tags: c#, wcf

Для программы понадобилось получить "истинное имя процесса" под этим я подразумеваю человеческое описание программы как в диспетчере задач:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как видно отображается красивое название открытой консоли Git "Git for Windows".
Я использую стандартную библиотеку user32.dll и функции из нее:

```
[DllImport("user32.dll")]
public static extern IntPtr GetForegroundWindow();
public static extern UInt32 GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hwnd, ref Int32 pid);
```

Так же во всех приведены примерах pid я получаю следующим путем:

```
// Получаю pid активного окна
GetWindowThreadProcessId(GetForegroundWindow(), ref pid);
// Получаю процесс исходя из pid активного окна
Process process = Process.GetProcessById(pid);
```

Вот с этим процессом я дальше и работаю. Я пытаюсь получить название с помощью следующих вариантов:

1) Самый приятный вариант, так как дает наиболее человеческие названия:

```
p.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription;
```

2) Просто получает заголовок окна приложения. Не всегда приятен, например в случае с git не работает(см. рисунок ниже):

```
p.MainWindowTitle;
```

[image]

Если брать у этого окна заголовок то получается белиберда и совсем не понятно.

3) Просто берем название процесса. Так же отклонил по понятным причинам (название процесса зачастую не равно название программы)

```
ProcessHeader = p.ProcessName;
```

Сейчас я использую все три варианта в том порядке в каком они приведены, если первый ничего не дает то используется второй, а если и со вторым облом то использую третий. До сих пор такая схем работала, но вот осечка (см. ниже). Ищу как апгрейдить.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.S. Название сайтов получаю другим способом, не через процессы.

Comment: "в случае с git не работает" - это скорее всего вы не разобрались с юникодными строками.

Comment: @ВладимирМартьянов, объясните пожалуйста подробнее, если не трудно :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если я не ошибаюсь, то на вкладке "Процессы" отображается описание процесса, а не его название. Само название отображается в "Подробности".

Описание процесса, храниться в самом файле. Для его получения вам надо вытащить инфу от туда примерно таким способом:

```
var fileVersionInfo = FileVersionInfo.GetVersionInfo(processPath); //получаем инфо из файла
var processDescription = fileVersionInfo.FileDescription; //Получаем описание.
```

Вот хорошая статья: [тык](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2016/02/process-description.html)

Comment: да статья хороша. Спасибо вам, это правда хорошо работает. Правда git он так и не определяет, ошибка в определении пути до него.